# When SAP Cloud SDK Template will upgrade to sprint boot v3.1

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

Possible Security Risk Due to Spring Boot 2.X is running out of Support 11-2023
SAP Cloud SDK project template has not been upgraded to Sprint boot v3.1 and Java 17, latest supported sprint boot version is 2.7.16

Important information:

Generate project template with maven command
SAP Cloud SDK project template has been upgraded to Sprint boot v3.1 and Java 17
SAP Cloud SDK project template has been upgraded to Sprint boot v2.7.16 and Java 11
Steps attempted to resolve the issue
In case of issues with any of our VDMs:
What happens when a request is performed directly via an HTTP client tool such as Postman?
In case that succeeds please provide details on the request such as URL, query parameters, header parameters, prerequisite requests (e.g. CSRF token), etc.
Potentially missing information (open questions you might have)
Impact / Priority
Security Risk.

Affected development phase: e.g. Getting Started, Development, Release, Production

Impact: e.g. No Impact, Inconvenience, Impaired, Blocked

Timeline: e.g. Go-Live is in 12 weeks.

What I have done: tried latest project template and find latest supported sprint boot version is 2.7.16.

What am I expected: latest project template has been upgraded to sprint boot v3.1 or is there any timeline when this upgrade will happen?

Answer (score 1):

We are currently working on our next major version (SDK V5), which is planned to be released by the end of November 2023.

This next major version will also come with a new archetype, based on Spring 6 + Spring Boot 3 (and ofc Java 17).
You can actually already get a little sneak-peek about that in our **Work in Progress** [documentation](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/v5/getting-started).